# How to perform validation of online connection in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have two database one database in webserver and other database in local
here i have to cheek in device if online connection is on then data should come from webserver database if online is off then data is come from sqlite local database and diplay data on iphone please help me in this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reachabilty.m and reachabilty.h to your project. In your controller which is active throughout the life of the program add the following lines and use the below callback.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
    [internetReachable startNotifier];

    // check if a pathway to a random host exists
    hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
    [hostReachable startNotifier];
```

The callback is as follows:

```
- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            break;

        }
    }

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: praveen ur ans is right but i want i have two thing one server database code and other localdata base code in api.m file then i want that if connectin in on then data come from server if  connection off then data should cheek from lical data base not from server how can i do this please help me

Comment: Well you get the status. If status has changed then read from local database, when connection is valid then check from server. Its not that hard, the states names' are very clear to indicate the connection status.

Comment: so i have to give server code in internet status and sqlite code host status like this

Answer (score 1):

In your appDelegate header file

```
NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus;
NetworkStatus internetConnectionStatus;
NetworkStatus localWiFiConnectionStatus;
@property NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus;
@property NetworkStatus internetConnectionStatus;
@property NetworkStatus localWiFiConnectionStatus;
```

in your appDelegate .m file

```
- (void)updateStatus
{
    self.remoteHostStatus           = [[Reachability sharedReachability] remoteHostStatus];
    self.internetConnectionStatus   = [[Reachability sharedReachability] internetConnectionStatus];
    self.localWiFiConnectionStatus  = [[Reachability sharedReachability] localWiFiConnectionStatus];
}

- (BOOL)isCarrierDataNetworkActive
{
    return (self.remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork);
}

- (NSString *)hostName
{
    return @"www.apple.com";
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  
    [[Reachability sharedReachability] setHostName:[self hostName]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) 
                                                 name:@"kNetworkReachabilityChangedNotification" 
                                               object:nil];
}
```

Comment: robin i try code but now i am confuse where i have to put my code i have cheek bot server connection and sqlite connection my ans is if user login again again then username and password should always cheek  first from server not in sqlite database if server off then username and password should cheek from sqlite database

Comment: you can check the connectivity using the above code than you can do what ever you requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reachability for network related information. See apple's sample of reachability.

Comment: i seen allready but how to code for that can u give me sample